# How to remove the inscription and link "Powered" in CMS

Tags: javascript, php, content-management-system, octobercms, refinerycms

I decided to create a website on CMS MediaVibe:

https://bigpin.ru

I'd like to remove the inscription with a link to the developer's site at the bottom of the site.
Searched in [index.php](https://pastebin.com/2Mzq3g8V) and found nothing. How can this label be removed?

```
if(is_admin()) {
echo "<pre class=\"footerdebug\" style='text-align:center'>Time Elapsed: ".(microtime(true) - $sttime)."s</pre> <br />
".$db->debug();
}
```

Comment: What does the posted code have to do with your question?

Comment: @Magnus Eriksson I don't really know programming and don't know where to look. I have posted a piece of code from the index.php file I have fully posted it at https://pastebin.com/2Mzq3g8V Please help! how can I remove this inscription at the bottom of the site. I don't understand the structure of this CMS at all.

Comment: Here is the site footer: https://pastebin.com/3UHijV35

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). _I don't really know programming and don't know where to look._ – Stack Overflow is about asking specific (programming) questions; it is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

div with class row-rights in tpl.footer.php
footer: [pastebin.com/3UHijV35](http://pastebin.com/3UHijV35)

```
<div class="row row-rights">
'.site_copy().'
</div>
```